# I want to automate a daily task, need certain info from pdf to go into specific areas of an excel file

Tags: bash, automation, software-design, office-automation

I’m working at a startup and would like to automate one of my daily tasks.

Currently we receive orders from 3 different distributors in either PDF or Webpage format and I must take some of the information from those PDF/Webpage orders and place them into an excel file in specific places, I’m currently copy and pasting to do this but I’m hoping to find a way to automate this perhaps using scripts.

I have some web development and JavaScript experience so I’m ok if this will involve some coding on my side to get this done, but I thought I would get some advice on avenues I could try. Maybe there are off the shelf solutions for this that would save even more time.

Is there anything I should know when embarking on research on how to accomplish this, any avenues you would suggest about how I solve the problem the most efficiently and easily? (best languages for the task ect.)

Any information would be much appreciated!